# How to convert dates to a different format from my database?

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my database, dates are stored in this format:

```
2013-03-14
```

I want to show dates on my web page formatted as:

```
2013-march-14
```

I have a lot of date data already stored in my database, so it's not possible to change my database. How can I do this conversion?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Too basic a question and answered innumerous times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

**Via MySQL**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn, '%Y-%M-%d') FROM table
```

**Via PHP**

```
$date = '2013-03-14';
echo date("Y-F-d", strtotime($date));
```

**Output**

```
2013-march-14
```

Comment: actually on PHP M would give you Mar not march, I can't remember what the format for full month is and for whatever reason the stupid manual not loading right now

Comment: @rantsh for full month `echo date("Y-F-d", strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL built-in [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function, with the specifiers `'%Y-%M-%d'` to format the date parts the way you want:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datefield, '%Y-%M-%d')
...
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ce1a/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this on PHP you could use the date function

```
$d = '2013-03-04';
echo date("Y-M-d", strtotime($d));  //2013-Mar-04
```

Comment: use `F` instead of `M` for full month